# How to Access an ß in a String in c

Tags: c

So I've been doing some string manipulation excersises for a while and I stumbled upon this german exercise where I have to implement a function that changes all ß's in a string input to ss's and also the opposite (from ss to ß) and save the changes on a new return string. I wonder how do you actually access the 'ß' in the string since the length of 'ß' is actually 2 and string[x] is not an option. I'm not allowed to use any function from the c string library. The result string has to be dynamically allocated.

This is what I have so far. Right now I'm still using
`returned[a] = *inputString;`
because I still don't know how to access the 'ß' seperately from other chars. Can anyone tell me how?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "base.h"

char *sharpStoDoubleS(char *inputString){
    int length = 0;
    //Count the length of string input
    for(char* new = inputString;*new != '\0';new++){
        length++;
    }
    //Result string
    String returned = malloc(length * sizeof(char) + 1);
    for(int a = 0;*inputString != '\0';inputString++, a++){
        if(*(inputString) == 's' && *(inputString + 1) == 's'){
            returned[a] = *inputString;
            a++;
            inputString++;
            returned[a] = *inputString;
        } else{
            returned[a] = *inputString;
        }
    }
    returned[length] = '\0';
    return returned;
}

int main()
{
    char *testString = "Strasse";
    printf("%s\n", sharpStoDoubleS(testString));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You recognize the *two byte* sequence `ss` with `if(*(inputString) == 's' && *(inputString + 1) == 's')`. You can do exactly the same for the two byte encoded `ß`.

Comment: I see. In this example, I have to change "Strasse" to "Straße". How do you have "ß" in the output returned string instead of "ss" since they are the same?

Comment: You have two bytes that you want to change to two other bytes. Change them one by one. Of course, you need to know the two-byte encoded value of `ß` first.

Comment: `"since the length of 'ß' is actually 2"` -- On some code pages, it is encoded as a single byte, for example `0xDF` in [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). In [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), it is encoded as two bytes (`0xC3,0x9F`). What type of encoding are you using?

Comment: Here is a nice blog article by one of the founders of Stack Overflow, which gives an overview on character encodings: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: In order to type `ß`, I use `ALT+0223`, because 223 is the ASCII-code of that character. Does that help?

Comment: @Dominique I think you mean [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), not ASCII. The code point 223 doesn't exist in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) :)

Comment: @Brian61354270: you're right: I have the tendency to use `ALT+064` for writing a monkey-tale on keyboards, not supporting the `@` character, and 64 is indeed the ASCII character of the monkey-tale. I'm using the same language when dealing with codes, larger than 128 too. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming UTF-8 encoding.

```
char* addToString(char* oldString, const char* postFix, size_t lenPost)
{
    size_t lenOld = oldString ? strlen(oldString) : 0;
    char* s = (char*)malloc(lenOld + lenPost + 1);
    strcpy(s, oldString?oldString:"");
    strncpy(s + lenOld, postFix, lenPost);
    s[lenOld + lenPost] = '\0';
    free(oldString);
    return s;
}

char* findAndReplace(const char* inputString, const char* search, const char* replacement)
{
    size_t lenSearch = strlen(search);
    size_t lenReplacement = strlen(replacement);

    char* result = NULL;

    size_t len = strlen(inputString);

    const char* start = inputString;
    const char* end = inputString + len;

    while (start < end)
    {
        const char* found = strstr(start, search);
        if (found)
        {
            result = addToString(result, start, found - start);
            result = addToString(result, replacement, lenReplacement);
            start = found + lenSearch;
        }
        else
        {
            result = addToString(result, start, end - start);
            start = end;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// convert ss to Sharp code
char* ssToSharp(const char* inputString) {

    char sharp[3] = { (char)0xc3, (char)0x9f, '\0'}; // UTF-8 for sharp
    return findAndReplace(inputString, "ss", sharp);
}

int main()
{
    const char* testString = "Strasse";
    printf("%s\n", ssToSharp(testString));
    return 0;
}
```

If you need a different encoding, you simply update this line:

```
char sharp[3] = { (char)0xc3, (char)0x9f, '\0' }; // UTF-8 for sharp
```

With the appropriate encoding sequence and null char.  For example, if you are using `0xDF` as the 1 byte encoding for sharp, it could be this:

```
char sharp[2] = { (char)0xdf, '\0'};
```